# How can I alternate between a Computer turn and a Player turn in a card game?

Tags: python, pygame, playing-cards

This is my first project using Pygame, and I've already taken a lot of inspiration from others' codes while trying to adapt it to my own purposes.

Game Rules:

I'm writing a card game that will be the Player vs the Computer. It is similar to Solitaire in that there are 4 play-piles that will take a sequence of cards from Ace-Queen (King being a wildcard that can be anything except a 7).
Each round starts with either the Player or Computer drawing cards to make a hand of 5.
The Player and Computer have a deck of 26 cards (the game is played with 2 standard decks), the objective is to play the top card on one of the 4 play piles and finish the deck before the other Player does.
To end a turn, a card from the hand must be thrown onto one of four bone piles, after which the next player's turn starts.

My Problem:

The Computer successfully draws a hand to make 5 cards, and then will randomly choose a card to throw on to the bone pile. The issue is that the Computer will continue to draw cards and play them onto the bone pile until the main deck is empty, at which point an error is raised (IndexError: pop from empty list).
From my understanding, the issue is that the draw_hand() function for the Computer continues to loop while the main loop runs.
My question is how to implement a code that will recognize when a card has been thrown onto a bone pile and then switch to the next player.

My code:

In the Deck class:

```
def draw_card(self):
    return self.cards.pop()
```

In the Computer class:

```
    def draw_hand(self, deck):
        while len(self.hand) < self.max_hand:
            self.hand.append(deck.draw_card())
        return self
```

In the Main file:

```
def computer_turn():
    computer.turn = True
    player.turn = False
    time.sleep(1)

def computer_end_turn():
    pile_choice = randint(1, 5)
    card_choice = randint(1, (len(computer.hand) - 1))
    throw_card = computer.hand.pop(card_choice)
    if pile_choice == 1:
        comp_bp1.cards.append(throw_card)
    elif pile_choice == 2:
        comp_bp2.cards.append(throw_card)
    elif pile_choice == 3:
        comp_bp3.cards.append(throw_card)
    elif pile_choice == 4:
        comp_bp4.cards.append(throw_card)

def player_turn():
    global app_running
    global moving
    computer.turn = False
    player.turn = True
    main_deck_rect = Rect(main_deck.rect)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            app_running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if main_deck_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                player.draw_hand(game_deck)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Mainloop:

```
while app_running:

    first_player()
    if computer.first_turn:
        if drawing == 0:
            computer.draw_hand(game_deck)
            computer_turn()
        else:
            computer_end_turn()
        drawing += 1
        drawing = drawing % 2

    else:
        player_turn()
```

I tried to implement different states for when the Computer is drawing a card, and when it's playing, but that still didn't work. I have a feeling that the issue is with the draw_hand() method that keeps running even after a card has been played from the hand, and I'm unsure as to how I can stop that from happening.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the code I wrote to determine which player goes first:

```
def first_player():
    if comp_top_card.name == 'king' or player_top_card.name == 'king':
        if comp_top_card.name == 'king':
            computer.first_turn = True
            player.first_turn = False
            # print('computer goes first')
        elif player_top_card.name == 'king':
            computer.first_turn = False
            player.first_turn = True
            # print('player goes first')
        elif comp_top_card.name and player_top_card.name == 'king':
            comp_choice = randint(0, 52)
            play_choice = randint(0, 52)
            if comp_choice > play_choice:
                computer.first_turn = True
                player.first_turn = False
                # print('computer goes first')
            else:
                computer.first_turn = False
                player.first_turn = True
                # print('player goes first')
    else:
        if comp_top_card.value > player_top_card.value:
            computer.first_turn = True
            player.first_turn = False
            # print('computer goes first')
        elif comp_top_card.value < player_top_card.value:
            computer.first_turn = False
            player.first_turn = True
            # print('player goes first')
        else:
            comp_choice = randint(0, 52)
            play_choice = randint(0, 52)
            if comp_choice > play_choice:
                computer.first_turn = True
                player.first_turn = False
                # print('computer goes first')
            else:
                computer.first_turn = False
                player.first_turn = True
                # print('player goes first')
```

(I'm sure this code if pretty messy and there's a more efficient way of doing things...but this is what worked for me hahahah)

Comment: Does computer.first_turn ever evaluate to False? I don't see any code setting this variable.

Comment: I've tried to set the computer.turn to False in various positions within the code, but I still end up with the same issue.

Comment: I realized you were talking about computer_first_turn(). That was determined by another code I've written...ill include it on an edit of the original post

Comment: *computer.first_turn

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with various alterations to the code and I got it to work the way I want by moving the first_player() function out of the main loop as that function should only be called once at the beginning of the game.
So now my code looks like this:

```
first_player()

while app_running:
    if computer.turn:
        if drawing == 0:
            computer.draw_hand(game_deck)
        else:
            computer_turn()
            check_for_turn_end()
        drawing += 1
        drawing = drawing % 2

    else:
        player_turn()
```